# Install Devkit: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, devkit

I feel very ashamed that i couldnt solve this problem on my on. Im googeling for several days now but somehow i have no success. When i try to follow the installing steps on: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit And on the end want to intall json i get this error:

```
 C:\Devkit>gem install json --platform=ruby
 Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
 Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
 ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    creating Makefile

  make "DESTDIR="
  generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
  compiling generator.c
  linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
  c:/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: can
  not find -lmsvcrt-ruby191
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [generator.so] Error 1


  Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
  .1/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
  Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
  0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Can somebody help me?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on  window 7 64  bit system
1) if you want to work with ruby version lesst then ruby 2.0
2) you need to install DevKit  32 bit from  http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/  on window 7 x64 bit

if you want to install ruby 2 or greater version on window 7 so you need to install  DevKit  64 bit

with  ruby 2 with 64 bit

with DevKit 64 bit on window 7  64 bit system ruby 32 bit will not work

but window 7 64 bit system with Devkit 32 bit and ruby 32 bit will work

this issue will not come